# Starting bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I need to teach myself bash scripting. I'm reading this ebook and it has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# hello.sh
# This is my first shell script!

declare -rx SCRIPT="hello.sh"
declare -rx who="/usr/bin/who"
declare -rx sync="/bin/sync"
declare -rx wc="/usr/bin/wc"

# sanity checks

if test -z "$BASH" ; then
    printf "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: please run this script with the BASH shell\n" >&2
    exit 192
fi

if test ! -x "$who" ; then
    printf "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: The command $who is not available - aborting\n" >&2
    exit 192
fi

if test ! -x "$sync" ; then
    printf "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: the command $sync is not available - aborting\n">&2
    exit 192
fi

if test ! -x "$wc" ; then
   printf "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: the command $wc is not available - aborting\n" >&2
   exit 192
fi

USERS = `$who | $wc -l`
if [ $USERS -eq 0 ] ; then
    $sync
fi

exit 0
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
hello.sh: line 32: USERS: command not found
hello.sh: line 33: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Am I not allowed to assign USERS to a the output of a command line in that fashion? If I run that line in the command line, it doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have to learn bash?  Every time I start with a small bash script thinking it's too simple to do in Python, I end up converting it to Python later.

Comment: That's a very poor quality script. An excellent resource is the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) along with [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: I'll check out that guide. Thanks. I need to learn bash for my internship. I wish it was just python but apparently the tools I'm going to be using requires bash.

Answer (score 5):

remove the spaces around the assignment `=`:

```
USERS=`$who | $wc -l`
```

Or it will be interpreted as a command `USERS` with the two parameters `=` and `%who | $wc -l`

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
USERS = `$who | $wc -l`
```

with

```
USERS=`$who | $wc -l`
```

Comment: Because it's not as sophisticated as a programming language, basically. In the shell, you can't learn what you did wrong unless you already know. :-( Reading the man page for bash really helped me learn, because it's terse and dense. :-)

Comment: Backticks are deprecated. Use `USERS=$($who | $wc -l)` instead. It is better readable and not so font-dependent, and can be nested without problems.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash (in fact in many shells) you can't have spaces between a variable name and the symbol =

in this case you need to write

```
USERS=`command`
```

or

```
USERS=$(command)
```

A variable sometimes act as a C++ Macro. If the variable USERS are empty and you type this:

```
if [ $USERS -eq 0 ] ; then
```

it will be interpreted like

```
if [ -eq 0 ] ; then
```

and the -eq is not a unary operator. to make it right you need write:

```
if [ "$USERS" -eq 0 ] ; then
```

to be interpreted

```
if [ "" -eq 0 ] ; then
```